# I don't understand how nested for loops work?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Here is a function that finds the integer that appears an odd number of times in a given array. What I don't understand is how the nested for-loop works in this particular function. Can somebody explain, please?

```js
function findOdd(A) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
      if (A[i] == A[j]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    
    if (count % 2 !== 0) {
      return A[i];
    }
  }
}

console.log(findOdd([20, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 20, 4, -1, -2, 5]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt at explaining what your code does. Hope that helps.

```js
// So we want our function to take a list of numbers, count the duplicates and return the first number whose count is not even (not a multiple of 2).

function findOdd(array) {
  // We start by setting up a variable that will hold the count of duplicates found
  var duplicatesCount = 0;
  
  // We start looping through our list of numbers to try to find the one whose duplicate count is not even
  for (var currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < array.length; currentIndex++) {
    // Here we have a number (array[currentIndex]). In order to know if it has a duplicate inside the list we need to loop over the list again, so that we can make a comparaison we all other entries one by one
    for (var comparaisonIndex = 0; comparaisonIndex < array.length; comparaisonIndex++) {
      // Here we have two numbers from the list (array[currentIndex] and array[comparaisonIndex]). We compare them to know if they have the same value.
      if (array[currentIndex] == array[comparaisonIndex]) {
        // If they have the same value we add one to the global duplicates count.
        duplicatesCount++;
      }
    }
    
    // Once we are here we have finished comparing the current number with all others from the list. The global count has been updated if needed, and, since we just want to return the first number whose duplicate count is not a multiple of two, we can check right away.
    if (duplicatesCount % 2 !== 0) {
      // Hey, we have a match ! No need to go on looping since we already found what we wanted. We return the current number.
      return array[currentIndex];
    }
    
  }
}

console.log(findOdd([20, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 20, 4, -1, -2, 5]))
```